# MySQL query to fetch all records between two given dates lied at least a day between two column dates

Tags: mysql

Employee table contains joinedDate and resignedDate column as date data type, need a mysql query to fetch worked employee records for a given between two dates.

Eg:
employee1 worked from 2014-01-01 to 2015-01-30 
employee2 is working from 2014-07-01 to 2015-08-30 
employee3 worked from 2014-12-01 to 2015-03-30

If I give start date as 2014-06-01 and end date as 2015-09-30, it should show all the three employee details. 
If I give start date as 2015-02-01 and end date as 2015-02-30, it should show 2nd and 3rd employee details

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting records between two dates using PHP from MySql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176847/selecting-records-between-two-dates-using-php-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found query myself, Please improve my MySQL query if you find any

```
SELECT 
* FROM
employeesTable WHERE (joinedDate <= '2014-06-01'
    AND resignedDate >= '2014-06-01')
    OR (joinedDate <= '2015-09-30'
    AND resignedDate >= '2015-09-30');
```